# Parcolumns: Unbalanced Columns

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, parcolumns

I'm using parcolumns to help design a resume but it's giving me some trouble by adding lots of extra space in the left and right columns.

Code (compile with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{48,138,255}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\color{lightblue}{#1}}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright\bfseries}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\raggedright}{}{1em}{} % Formatting subsection
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}



\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\begin{parcolumns}[sloppy,colwidths={1=0.28\textwidth}]{2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%LEFT COLUMN
\colchunk[1]{%
\par{\Huge \bfseries Joel \\ Hawkins}
\section{}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.26\textwidth} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{square}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
Portland, OR \\
+1 (555) 555 - 5555 \\
\href{mailto:mail@domain.edu}{mail@domain.edu} \\
\href{http://google.com}{my webpage}
\end{center}

\null
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%RIGHT COLUMN
\colchunk[2]{%


%%%%Education
\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{l l}

\textbf{Reed College}                   & \textbf{\blue{Bachelor of Arts in Physics}} \\
\textbf{\blue{Current}}                         & \footnotesize \textbf{Class of 2015} \\
\footnotesize Portland, OR              & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%------------------------------------------------

\textbf{Boise High}              & \footnotesize \textbf{Class of 2011} \\
\textbf{School}             & \small Recipient of Academic Achievement Award \\
\footnotesize{Boise, ID}        & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

\end{tabular}

%%%%Work
\section{Work}

\begin{tabular}{l l}

\textbf{Reed College}                   & \textbf{\blue{Apple Certified Hardware Technician}} \\
\textbf{\blue{Current}}                 & \textbf{Computer Hardware Services} \\
September 2011                      & Solve students' \& faculty's hardware/software problems \\
\footnotesize{Portland, OR}             & Facilitate \& automate software deployment for all machines \\
                                    & Repair machines \& provide support for students/faculty \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%------------------------------------------------

\textbf{PCS Learning Center}                & \textbf{\blue{Assistant Teacher}} \\
Summer 2012                         & Bolstered scientific skills in students (physics, robotics, code) \\
\footnotesize{Boise, ID}                    & Designed \& managed company website incl.~photo editing \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%------------------------------------------------

\textbf{AeroSpecialties Inc.}               & \textbf{\blue{Machine Shop Assistant}} \\
2010-2011                           & Operated CNC machines \\
\footnotesize{Boise, ID}                    & Assembled parts according to industry regulations \\
                                    & Performed extended data entry for migrating computer systems \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\null
}
\end{parcolumns}


\end{document}
```

This gives the following (some unrelated code omitted):

[image: Parcolumns adding extra space]

Obviously there's WAY too much blank space in the left column between my name and also extra space between the Work and Experience sections which I didn't ask for. I think it's trying to balance the columns weirdly?

Maybe you see what I'm trying to do here and I haven't found another package that can effectively create two columns of uneven width (sort of like having two minipages displayed side by side?). I've tried using `\vfill`, `\null`, `\mbox{}` but none of those work. How do I get it to not add space and even the columns?

Comment: please make your code into a complete document that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Does that code demonstrate the problem? I can't tell. It certainly doesn't match the output and I don't have the images it uses so I've no way to test it. (If I just use demo mode, obviously that will affect the spacing so be useless.) Please post a minimal example which others can compile to reproduce the problem. You are adding a lot of space manually which is probably not helping.

Comment: It does compile if you use XeLaTeX. I removed the graphics just now. The font in the image and code will not match because it's not a standard font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use two minipages and add the spacing you need manually.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % Sans serif font
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{url,parskip,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{48,138,255}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\color{lightblue}{#1}}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\raggedright\bfseries}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\raggedright}{}{1em}{} % Formatting subsection
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}



\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%LEFT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{.28\textwidth}
\vspace*{0pt}
{\Huge \bfseries Joel \\ Hawkins\par}

\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{square}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
Portland, OR \\
+1 (555) 555 - 5555 \\
\href{mailto:mail@domain.edu}{mail@domain.edu} \\
\href{http://google.com}{my webpage}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.68\textwidth}
\vspace*{0pt}
%%%%Education
\section{Education}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}

\textbf{Reed College}                   & \textbf{\blue{Bachelor of Arts in Physics}} \\
\textbf{\blue{Current}}                         & \footnotesize \textbf{Class of 2015} \\
\footnotesize Portland, OR              & \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%------------------------------------------------

\textbf{Boise High}              & \footnotesize \textbf{Class of 2011} \\
\textbf{School}             & \small Recipient of Academic Achievement Award \\
\footnotesize{Boise, ID}        & \\
\end{tabularx}

%%%%Work

\bigskip

\section{Work}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}

\textbf{Reed College}                   & \textbf{\blue{Apple Certified Hardware Technician}} \\
\textbf{\blue{Current}}                 & \textbf{Computer Hardware Services} \\
September 2011                      & Solve students' \& faculty's hardware/software problems \\
\footnotesize{Portland, OR}             & Facilitate \& automate software deployment for all machines \\
                                    & Repair machines \& provide support for students/faculty \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%------------------------------------------------

\textbf{PCS Learning Center}                & \textbf{\blue{Assistant Teacher}} \\
Summer 2012                         & Bolstered scientific skills in students (physics, robotics, code) \\
\footnotesize{Boise, ID}                    & Designed \& managed company website incl.~photo editing \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
%------------------------------------------------

\textbf{AeroSpecialties Inc.}               & \textbf{\blue{Machine Shop Assistant}} \\
2010-2011                           & Operated CNC machines \\
\footnotesize{Boise, ID}                    & Assembled parts according to industry regulations \\
                                    & Performed extended data entry for migrating computer systems \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't try this sooner.